# Тип INTERVAL и функция extract

Tags: sql, oracle

Привет . 
Встретил тип INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND и INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH специально для хранения интервалов. 
Мне кажется что использование функции extract решает все задачи и более удобна .

Пример

```
select inter,
       extract (day from inter) days,
       extract (hour from inter) hours,
       extract (minute from inter) minutes,
       extract (second from inter) seconds
from
(select 
  cast(date2 as timestamp) - cast(date1 as timestamp) inter
FROM
(
  SELECT
    TO_DATE('2014-06-06 10:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') DATE1,
    to_date('2014-06-06 11:25', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') date2
  from dual
));
```

вопрос зачем использовать эти неудобные интервалы которые и ответ дают в трудном формате

```
service_interval := (end_date - start_date) YEAR TO MONTH;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(service_interval); //+06-11
```

Это что нужно еще и парсить дополнительно ? Не вижу использовать это .

Answer (score 1):

Интервалы можно применять не только для получения разницы между датами, но и для получения новой даты. Пример:

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') CURRENT_TIME,
  TO_CHAR(sysdate + INTERVAL '1:15:2' HOUR TO SECOND, 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') with_interval,
  TO_CHAR(sysdate + 1 / 24 + 1 / 24 / 60 * 15 + 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 * 2, 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') without_interval
FROM
  dual
```

Вторая и третья колонки показывают текущее время увеличенное на 1 час 15 минут 2 секунды. По моему личному мнению запись через интервал имеет более информативный вид и легче для редактирования.

Касательно применения. Еще ни разу не приходилось использовать данные типы. Но мне кажется, что для хранения в базе гораздо удобнее использовать интервал. Для примера:

```
SELECT
  (
    TO_DATE('2015.01.01 23:59:59', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') -
    TO_DATE('2015.01.01 22:47:18', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss')
  ) DAY TO SECOND with_interval, /* 0 1:12:41.0*/
  (
    TO_DATE('2015.01.01 23:59:59', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') -
    TO_DATE('2015.01.01 22:47:18', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss')
  ) without_interval /*0,050474537037037037037037037037037037037*/
FROM
  dual
```